# How to use <say-as> tag in vxml to Voice out Names?

Tags: ivr, vxml, voicexml

I m trying to develop a vxml app to play a welcome prompt with names.
for example "Hello Mr Karthikeyan.. welcome to stackoverflow helpline..."
I want system to voice out the name without spoiling the User Experience..
is there any the possible values for interpret-as/format attribute of < say-as > tag in Nuance Platform? something like  ?

Comment: Be aware that there is a noticeable percentage of names that are pronounced poorly and I've found customers that can reactive very negatively to having their name mispronounced.  If you do implement this, I recommend monitoring it closely and making sure it is quick and easy to update the pronunciation dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no say-as or interpret-as attributes that will help with proper names. To fine tune the Text-To-Speech (TTS) engine for proper names you will need to update the TTS dictionary with the names that will be voiced back and the proper pronunciation. Nuance sells some packages that can update their TTS dictionary with a large list of common names.